# Theano import error: cannot import name stacklists

Tags: python, theano

```
from theano.tensor import stacklists, scalars, matrices

from theano import function

a, b, c, d = scalars('abcd')

X = stacklists([[a, b], [c, d]])   
f = function([a, b, c, d], X)
f(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

this is my program.
i am getting following error.can anybody help

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e4e1f4f75320> in <module>()
----> 1 from theano.tensor import stacklists, scalars, matrices

      2 from theano import function

      3 a, b, c, d = scalars('abcd')
      4 X = stacklists([[a, b], [c, d]])
      5 f = function([a, b, c, d], X)

ImportError: cannot import name stacklists
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have an old version of Theano; `stacklist` was [recently introduced/renamed](https://github.com/mrocklin/Theano/commit/8eefe5a0094e84d470865e42cc16edcbdeda58e3) (a month ago). Sou you should update to the latest/dev version. If you want to stay in your version try importing `tensor_of_scalars` instead of `stacklist`.

To update follow the instructions [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#install).

Comment: thank you elyase. can't we  update this version.how to update.

Answer (score 1):

This error can be caused by one of two things.

The first one is pretty obvious: does `theano.tensor` define a name `stacklists`?  Should it be, for example, `stacklist`?

Secondly, it can happen if something else you're importing has already imported the name in a way where doing so again would cause a circular reference.  The second would have to be fixed by looking at your source files.

Comment: from theano.tensor import stacklists, scalars, matrices
 means we are importing some predefined func stacklists,scalars and matrices into my pgm. then hw come ur two answers will be match with this....i cldnt get your ans